# Jquery html not working dont know why?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, jquery-selectors

This is the html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <title>Ingredient</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8" />
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/receta.min.css" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile.structure-1.1.0.min.css" /> 
      <script src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script> 
      <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.js"></script> 
      <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/ingredients.js"></script>  

      <h1><center>INGREDIENTES</h1>
    <ul>
     <li onclick="this.parentNode.removeChild(this);">
      <input type="hidden" name="ingredients[]" value="Cheese" />
      Cheese
     </li>
     <li onclick="this.parentNode.removeChild(this);">
      <input type="hidden" name="ingredients[]" value="Ham" />
      Ham
     </li>
    </ul>
    <select onchange="selectIngredient(this);">
     <option value="Cheese">Cheese</option>
     <option value="Olives">Olives</option>
     <option value="Pepperoni">Pepperoni</option>
     <option value="Milk">Milk</option>
    </select>

      </html>
```

This is the jquery

```
    function selectIngredient(select)
    {
      var $ul = $(select).prev('ul');

      if ($ul.find('input[value=' + $(select).val() + ']').length == 0)
        $ul.append('<li onclick="$(this).remove();">' +
          '<input type="hidden" name="ingredients[]" value="' + 
          $(select).val() + '" /> ' +
          $(select).find('option[selected]').text() + '</li>');
    }
```

[image: This is what i need to see when yo select another ingredient this one should be putted with the other ones]

When i run this html and jquery it doesnt work. It should put another ingredients to the list if i select it but it doesnt happen.

Comment: you have an extra `<center>` tag (that is BTW deprecated nowadays) inside `<h1>`

Answer (score 3):

I think here:

```
$(select).find('option[selected]').text()
```

you actually mean this:

```
$(select).find('option:selected').text()
```

But why not using `$(select).val()` again? On your HTML, the text and the values are just the same.

Comment: How would it look like at the end with the changes you say ?

Comment: `$ul.append('<li onclick="$(this).remove();">' +
          '<input type="hidden" name="ingredients[]" value="' + 
          $(select).val() + '" /> ' +
          $(select).val() + '</li>');`

Comment: I dont understand can you se the picture i just uploaded.

Comment: @JuanCarlos Sorry, but I don't understand what you don't understand. If you change your code as I say, it should look just like the picture you posted.

Comment: @JuanCarlos Sorry if this is harsh, but look at your own code and look at the code on my answer. I told you exactly which part of your code should be replaced, and what it should be replaced with. If you can't figure that out yourself, I'm afraid you're asking on the wrong site.

Comment: I put it the way you told me and where you told me but it doesnt put the new ingredient in the list. But thanks anyway.

Comment: @JuanCarlos Sorry, I didn't notice jquery mobile. It's wrapping your select element with a lot of HTML. You need to replace the `var $ul ...` line with this: `var $ul = $(select).closest('.ui-select').prev('ul');`. Demo at http://jsbin.com/itozop/1/edit

Answer (score 2):

### *[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/ujitas/3/edit)*

**(purified) HTML**

```
<h1>INGREDIENTES</h1>
<ul>
 <li>
  <input type="hidden" name="ingredients[]" value="Cheese" />
  Cheese
 </li>
 <li>
  <input type="hidden" name="ingredients[]" value="Ham" />
  Ham
 </li>
</ul>


<select>
 <option value="Cheese">Cheese</option>
 <option value="Olives">Olives</option>
 <option value="Pepperoni">Pepperoni</option>
 <option value="Milk">Milk</option>
</select>
```

**(funnyfied) jQ**

```
function selectIngredient(select){
      
      var selVal = $(select).val();
      var $ul    = $(select).prev('ul');
      var exists = $ul.find('input[value=' + selVal +']').length;
  
      if ( !exists ){        
          $ul.append('<li>' +
          '<input type="hidden" name="ingredients[]" value="' + selVal + '" /> ' +
          selVal + '</li>');        
      }
}


$('ul').on('click','li',function(){
   $(this).remove();
});

$('select').change(function(){
   selectIngredient(this);
});
```

If you like it more structured you can use:

```
    var input = $('<input />',{
          type : 'hidden',
          name : 'ingredients[]',
          value: selVal
    });
    $('<li />', { text: selVal }).prepend( input ).appendTo( $ul );
```

Comment: @JuanCarlos you're welcome. Inside the demo it works; if you have questions feel free to ask.